# Facebook `share_open_graph` share ignores `og:description` when `og:image` is present

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, share, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to set the `og` values shared to Facebook dynamically using the [share_open_graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#open-graph) method:

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'share_open_graph',
        action_type: 'og.shares',
        action_properties: JSON.stringify({
            object: {
                'og:url': 'https://myurl.com',
                'og:title': 'TITLE',
                'og:description': 'DESCRIPTION',
                'og:image': 'https://image.jpg'
            }
        })
    });
```

I'm finding that when this method is called with the `og:image` included, the `og:description` doesn't appear in the share dialogue that pops up. But when I remove the image, the description is shown.

Can anyone suggest how I can share both pieces of data? I'm using v2.10 of the Facebook SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Through painful experimentation I've discovered that if the description string is less than 92 characters Facebook won't display it in the share dialogue. If it's less than 92 characters but there's no image, it displays fine.

Totally weird, but there it is.